# Make GridLayoutManager obey the width parameter of LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

The [`GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.html) states that:

> Note that if the orientation is [`VERTICAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#VERTICAL), the width parameter is ignored and if the orientation is [`HORIZONTAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#HORIZONTAL) the height parameter is ignored because child view **is expected to fill all of the space given to it**.

Is there any clean way around this limitation?

My use case is to have two columns with widths matching their children ([`WRAP_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT)) and a third column freely shrinking and expanding depending on the available width:

```
|---|------|-------------------------------|
|ABE|Fills |This one                       |
|A  |The   |Expands                        |
|   |Column|Freely                         |
|---|------|-------------------------------|
```

I've tried [`WRAP_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT), but it only shrinks the contents of the column, but not the actual column.

One not-so-good way to avoid this would be to use [`HORIZONTAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#HORIZONTAL), transpose the data and keep calling [`setSpanCount`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanCount(int)), but that kinda defeats the purpose of using a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Another way would be to implement a custom [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html), but that seems a lot of work.